# How to group up NER tags in order to get data from sentence as a whole?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

Through the CoreNLP library, upon calling `ner()` on a `CoreLabel` I receive a string indicating its named entity tag (such as `PERSON` or `DATE`).

However, I know of no way of comparing tokens in a sentence against each other. For example: (text of tokens surrounded in backticks)

```
`Ellen` PERSON
`Wexler `PERSON
`,` O
`February` DATE
`9` DATE
`,` DATE
`2016` DATE
```

**Through CoreNLP, How do I group up the person tags in order to get the name `Ellen Wexler`? Or the date tags in order to get `February 9, 2016`, or another representation that I could eventually turn into a Date/Calendar object in Java?** I have looked at the example given [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html), however that only finds the ner tags for each individual core label. It does not provide me a way to group consecutive, identical ner tags together.

**What I have tried:**
I have written a for loop that iterates over the sentence and finds X number of consecutive, identical ner tags (so if X is 2 and the ner tag is `PERSON`, it will find 2 consecutive PERSONs). In this scenario, that is `Ellen Wexler`. However, this breaks down when punctuation comes into play, as punctuation, depending on context, is given the ner tag of its adjacent tokens. In addition, there must be some way to do this through CoreNLP.

**My Resarch**:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45349957/merge-consecutive-tokens-with-same-ner-tag-in-corenlp-conll-output) similar question has not been answered. The CoreNLP home page provides no answer, as it only provides an example regarding analysis of individual core labels/tokens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More traditionally you want to use the `entitymentions` annotator.

In version 3.9.0 which has just been beta-released, the `ner` annotator will automatically create entity mentions which link tokens together that belong to the same entity mention.

You can see some example usage of a new API to see how to easily access the entity mentions.  Some of the features of this class aren't in the beta of 3.9.0 on the site, but will be added in an updated version very soon.

Helpful demo code:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/examples/BasicPipelineExample.java

Comment: Thank you, this works wonderfully. However, can you clarify the difference between a CoreMap and CoreSentence? Old questions that use entity mentions use CoreMap, however your example in addition to my program use CoreSentence.

Comment: CoreSentence is a new class that was added recently.  Old answers should still work but new syntax has been added to make it easier to work with pipelines.

Comment: A CoreSentence is just a wrapper around a CoreMap, if you look at the CoreSentence code you'll notice it contains an underlying CoreMap

Comment: In the future the goal is to have the CoreSentence be a subclass of CoreMap instead of a wrapper, but that was going to require too much work and we wanted to get these new convenience classes out with the 3.9.0 release.